# PHP table linking

Tags: php

I have two tables in MySQL, let's say table A and B. In table A I have details of my clients, and in table B I have additional details that is intended to link to table A via member_id.

I have a PHP page where I call information from table A with the following code and echo it to display. This is working fine:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members
WHERE member_msisdn='$slusername'");
```

on the same page I have another query that should draw information from table B but it should use the table A member_id to display the right information

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recipients
WHERE member_id='NOT SURE WHAT TO PLACE HERE'");
```

If I call in the first section the member_id, is there away I can tell it in the second section to link information from table B?

Comment: [JOIN](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)s to the rescue!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM members a  
INNER JOIN recipients b
ON id.members = id.recipients
WHERE member_msisdn=$slusername
```

Where the `ON` statement indicates the field both tables share.